# Volume of a cut paraboloid

Tags: volume

I have a cut paraboloid made from parabola $y(x)=c+x-ax^2$ and $x = 0$ line.
How do I compute volume of this cut paraboloid?
I researched on Wolfram. [see formula 16 and 17](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Paraboloid.html)

Comment: Do you know disk or shell method? Alternatively, do you know how to set up a double or triple integral to calculate the volume of a solid?

Comment: No. I don't know disk method. Could you provide a link to read about it. Thank you.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx

Comment: Oh, by the way, at first I thought that was $y=0$ line. So, if the line is $x=0$, then I don't understand your question, because there is no bounded region.

Comment: Sorry, $x=0$ and $y=0$. Rotating around $y$.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62233/discussion-between-theportakal-and-alex-gawkins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to take a step back and look at the basic definitions. The area and centroid are given by

$$
A=\int\!\!\!\int dy~dx=\int y(x)~dx\\
R_x=\frac{\int\!\!\!\int x~dy~dx}{\int\!\!\!\int dy~dx}=\frac{1}{A}\int x~y(x)~dx\\
R_y=\frac{\int\!\!\!\int y~dy~dx}{\int\!\!\!\int dy~dx}=\frac{1}{2A}\int y^2(x)~dx\\
$$

And finally, Pappus's $2^{nd}$ Centroid Theorem states that the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $V=2πRA$. Therefore, for rotation about the $y$-axis, we can say that

$$V=2\pi\int_0^{x_{max}} x~y(x)~dx$$

where $x_{max}$ is the point on positive $x$-axis where $y=0$, i.e.

$$x_{max}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4ac}}{2a}$$

Thus

$$V=2\pi\int_0^{x_{max}} x~(c+x-ax^2)~dx$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Your solution and [the solution I accepted] https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2358978/356852 gives different results. Why? $\pi*\int{[k+\sqrt{l-m*y}]^2}dy$

Comment: @AlexGawkins The desired result can be found equivalently by $$V=2\pi\int xy(x)~dx$$ and $$V=\pi \int x^2(y)~dy.$$ In your comment, I do not think you have correctly represented $x(y)$. My solution is correct; I have verified it numerically for random $a$ and $c$. You have accepted a solution that wasn't really a solution at all, was it? I recommend that you change that.

Answer (score 0):

This volume can be calculated using disk or shell method.

Paul's online notes is a good source, here is a link with many examples:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx